# Random numbers from specific range

Tags: c++, random

I want to display random numbers specific range `[from, to]`. Following code writes out the value but something is not working properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int draw(int from_to, int to_from)
{
    return (rand()%to_from)+from_to;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int start,stop;
    cout << "First number: " << endl;
    cin >> start;
    cout << "Last number: " << endl;
    cin >> stop;
    int x=20;
    do
    {
        cout << draw(start,stop) << endl;
        x--;
    } while(x>0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it not working properly?

Comment: consider using the [facilities provided by the <random> header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

Comment: displays random numbers out of range

Comment: Your `% to_from` is probably wrong. That'll generate numbers between 0 and stop-1, then add them to start to make the range start to (start + stop - 1). Which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Agree with @Borgleader; if you still prefer staying with `rand` be aware that `rand() % something` produces rather bad distribution. Better is `rand() * something / (RAND_MAX + 1)` – provided no overflow can occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your desired range of calculation is between `from_to` and `to_from`, your calculation looks a bit odd:

```
int draw(int from_to, int to_from) {
    return (rand()%to_from)+from_to;
}
```

When we fill in the values `5` and `10`, we get the following formula:

```
(rand()% 5) + 10
```

This would have a big change of exceeding the boundary of `from_to`, which in this case is `10`. In order to fix this, you can use the following formula instead:

```
return rand() % (to_from-from_to + 1) + from_to;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try C++11 features for generating random number from specified range:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int from = 0;
    int to   = 100;

    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generator(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> distribution(from, to);

    std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Crandom%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+from+%3D+0%3B%0A++++int+to+++%3D+100%3B%0A%0A++++std::random_device+device%3B%0A++++std::mt19937+generator(device())%3B%0A++++std::uniform_int_distribution%3Cstd::mt19937::result_type%3E+distribution(from,+to)%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+distribution(generator)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)